# How to change of selected item in custom Horizontal List View in android

Tags: android, selecteditem, onitemclick, horizontallist

I am using custom Horizontal listview, My need is to change the color of Clicked item.

Here is the code of my XML

```
    <com.meetme.android.horizontallistview.HorizontalListView
            android:id="@+id/hlvCustomList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp" 
                          />

                selectedRow = view; //view is the onitemSelectListner View
                if (selectedRow != null) {

                    selectedRow.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                }

                        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
```

I have tried this code on ItemClick but not working for me.

Please suggest me appropriate way to do this.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it contains no research effort being made.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the background for the `HorizontalListView`

Add `android:background="@drawable/listviewbackground"` and write this code in `listviewbackground.xml` in your drawable folder. Here i'm changing `colors`, you can try to change anything as per your needs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
       android:color="#aabbcc"/> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_activated="true"
       android:color="#fedcba"/> <!-- selected -->
   <item android:color="#abcdef"/> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

Comment: I am using  using com.meetme.android.horizontallistview.HorizontalListView 
So Your answer is not working for me.